# NSUserDefaults on a user by user basis

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, cfpreferences

Our iOS app allows various users to log into the app using an external service, and I would like each of those users to be able to store their own unique preferences.

Looking at `NSUserDefaults` you cannot store user specific defaults without creating an `NSDictionary` for each user, which at this point sounds like my last resort.

I do see that `CFPreferences` can store preferences for user, application, host etc, which sounds like what I want, but is much more low level.

**My question is, are there any `NSUserDefaults` subclasses out there that easily allow setting user by user defaults? Or, is there a higher level library that uses `CFPreferences`? Just looking for a good solution for per-user preferences.**

Comment: @vadian - This is on iOS.

Comment: "user" and "host" are not the concepts you want on iOS. The only user available to applications is "mobile", which all apps run as. The "host" argument is only used on OSX.

Comment: Is it possible to store the user's preferences server-side?

Comment: You can make your own and save them in documents folder so they could be synced into iCloud.

Comment: Possibly server side would work, but wouldn't want to build a server implementation just for this.

Comment: @Andy - Possibly could just write them to a plist file. That is an idea...

Comment: iOS has no framework-visible concept of multiple users, especially at the app level.  Anything you do for multi-user support will have to be completely custom.

You should probably create a class to store user settings.  This class can be written to use one plist per user or to store settings in NSUserDefaults with one dictionary per user.  Either way, you have to implement it.  I don't think one way is particularly more difficult than another.

Comment: I ended up writing a quick class for this and put it on github: https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any good answers, so I ended up writing my own class to deal with saving multiple user defaults:

https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSUserDefaults